# Displaying values of a table that falls BETWEEN specific dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, between

I am quite new to SQL but I was wondering how to achieve the following. How do I get specific values that fall in the year 2013 when the date format in the table is looking something like this:

```
1   94  pH  02-02-2012 11:48 AM 1200001
2   103 pH  09-06-2012 11:48 AM 1200002
3   96  pH  15-06-2011 3:12 PM  1200003
4   111 HP  02-02-2011 8:55 AM  1200015
5   89  JP  12-12-2012 1:32 PM  1200007
6   90  Nic 19-06-2012 3:12 PM  1200009
7   99  Nic 21-01-2013 9:55 AM  1200012
8   102 pH  09-01-2013 3:23 PM  1200011
9   96  pH  15-02-2013 2:54 PM  1200003
```

I also want to use the BETWEEN clause that will almost look something like this:

```
USE Daspoort_Clinic
Go

SELECT Con_Consult_Date,
  GETDATE() AS qwe,
  CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS qweewq,
  CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 105) AS asd
FROM Consultation
--WHERE Con_Consult_Date BETWEEN '01-01-2013' AND '31-12-2013'
GO
```

I can't seem to get this to work because it only takes the GETDATE() value and will not convert the dates (of type varchar(30)) in the Con_Consult_Date column.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Joe

Comment: So your dates are stored as strings in the database? That'll be a problem for `BETWEEN`, that may mean you can't use it. I'd change the datatype of those columns to be date/times, then what you have should work.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I edited the code where I am trying to convert the date but I have no luck in doing so. Any ideas why its not successful?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use BETWEEN for datetime values; it only works reliably for date and smalldate values. You will have to manually construct you range predicate like this:

```
WHERE ThisBeginDateTime <= dateTimeColumn AND dateTimeColumn < NextBeginDateTime
```

If this is a join predicate instead of a filter predicate, you may have to self-join (use a LEFT JOIN) the Periods table to itself in order to obtain the appropriate values for NextBeginDateTime.

While it is definitely preferred to have your datetime values stored as such in the database, instead of as strings, this method will still work with properly formatted string representations of the datetime values.

P.S.

The difficulty with using BETWEEN with datetime values is that it is difficult, *and implementation and version dependent*, to properly determine the *last possible valid and representable datetime* in a date range.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT Consult_No, Con_Hist_BMI, Con_Hist_UrineTest,Con_Consult_Date,Patient_No
FROM Consultation
WHERE Con_Consult_Date BETWEEN '01-01-2013 12:00 AM' AND '31-12-2013 11:59 PM'
```